# Experiencing the "socket hang up" error while testing my application on

Tags: postman

Experiencing the "socket hang up" error while testing my application on http://localhost:6002/register

I've double-checked all configurations, and everything seems to be in order.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any tips or suggestions to help resolve it would be greatly appreciated!

#Programming #ErrorHandling #WebDevelopment #TechHelp #SocketHangUp #Troubleshooting#Programming #ErrorHandling #WebDevelopment #TechHelp #SocketHangUp #Troubleshooting#Programming #ErrorHandling #WebDevelopment #TechHelp #SocketHangUp #Troubleshooting#Programming #ErrorHandling #WebDevelopment #TechHelp #SocketHangUp #Troubleshooting

Comment: Socket Hangup errors can be client or server side.  This might be a connectivity issue, so if you are on a Windows device you might want to check the local firewall settings (as port 6002 isn't a standard port).  You also might want to check http vs https.  Check the Accept Headers for the API.  There are a bunch of other potential reasons.  I would recommend providing more details about the API and potentially the code.  You've double checked the configurations...  Which configurations?  Provide details on what you have already checked.

Answer (score 0):

if all your configurations are correct the errors are on the Postman which is

make sure your body is JSON type like this

[image]

Comment: How do you know that this specific API requires an JSON body?  The poster hasn't given you any details about the API that would imply that.  Incorrect body type would generally return a 4xx http status code indicating a client issue.  Socket hang ups can be client or server side (but generally mean the "server said no").

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.